# array cross-over loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

let's say i have this code :

```
let variants = []  

let variant = {
    variantName: 'Size',
    variantItems: ['XL','MD','SM']
}
variants.push(variant)

variant = {
    variantName: 'Color',
    variantItems: ['Red','Blue']
}
variants.push(variant)
```

okay, now how do i output it to something like this :

[image]

and the `variants` array can contain many `variant` object

and if there is one more object inside `variants` array :

```
variant = {
    variantName: 'Material',
    variantItems: ['Plastic','Wood', 'Ceramic']
}
variants.push(variant)
```

and it will be outputted like this :

[image]

Please help, i very appreciate your help...

Comment: You do not know how to append elements to table?

Comment: @Justinas not append to table, but to get the data from `variants` array, output just a string it's fine

Comment: Shouldn’t the fourth line in the second sample be “Size: XL, Color: Blue, Material: Plastic”? You’re changing the third parameter, then the first, then the second, for some reason…

Comment: @Xufox yeah that's my mistake, sorry i'm gonna fix the example. but what you mean is correct, that's what i meant too, can you help me please? i'm stuck on this for 3 days and still doesn't figure it out.. Thank's anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a functional ES6 approach.

```js
let variants = [{
    variantName: "Size",
    variantItems: [
      "XL",
      "MD",
      "SM"
    ]
  },
  {
    variantName: "Color",
    variantItems: [
      "Red",
      "Blue"
    ]
  }];

let crossJoined = new Array(variants.reduce((product, variant) => (product * variant.variantItems.length), 1))
  .fill(0)
  .reduce(crossJoin => {
    crossJoin.data.push(crossJoin.currentIndexes.map((itemIndex, variantIndex) => `${variants[variantIndex].variantName}: ${variants[variantIndex].variantItems[itemIndex]}`).join(", "));

    let incrementableIndex = variants.length - crossJoin.currentIndexes
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .findIndex((itemIndex, variantIndex) => variants[variants.length - variantIndex - 1].variantItems.length > itemIndex + 1) - 1;

    crossJoin.currentIndexes[incrementableIndex]++;
    crossJoin.currentIndexes = crossJoin.currentIndexes.map((value, index) => (index > incrementableIndex
      ? 0
      : value));
    
    return (crossJoin.currentIndexes.length == variants.length
      ? crossJoin
      : crossJoin.data);
  }, {
    data: [],
    currentIndexes: new Array(variants.length).fill(0)
  }).join("\n");

console.log(crossJoined);
```

First, an array is created with a length of all `variantItems` array lengths multiplied, then it is zero-filled. Next, we `reduce` it to another array.

`crossJoin` is the aggregator that holds an object of this structure most of the time:

```
{
  data: [ … ],
  currentIndexes: [ 1, 3 ] // Corresponds to variants[0].variantItems[1]
                           //            and variants[1].variantItems[3]
}
```

That is “most of the time”, until the end, where `currentIndexes` won’t be used anymore and *only* its `data` property is returned.

So in each `reduce` iteration, we first push a new entry to `crossJoin.data`, using `crossJoin.currentIndexes` and the indexes of that array. Removing `.join(", ")` will result in an entry of the structure

```
[ "Size", "XL" ]
```

Next, we need to increment the numbers in `crossJoin.currentIndexes`:

`[ 0, 0 ]` should be incremented to `[ 0, 1 ]`, because there is a second color at the index `1`. `[ 0, 1 ]` should be incremented to `[ 1, 0 ]`, because there is no third color, but a second size, but then we need the first color again, and so on. The last valid index array is `[ 2, 1 ]` which corresponds to the third size and the second color, which is the last combination.

`incrementableIndex` is the last possible index that can still be incremented. Once incremented, all subsequent indexes have to be `0`.

You see those `variants.length -` *something* `- 1` twice, because you need to find the first index *from the end*, so you have to `reverse` (*a copy of* — hence the `slice`) the array, then re-interpret the found index as an index from the start again.

The `return` returns this `crossJoin` object for the next iteration. The condition `crossJoin.currentIndexes.length == variants.length` applies to the very end, where no index can be incremented anymore. It adds a `NaN` to the `currentIndexes` array, so the lengths don’t match, and instead of filtering out or preventing the `NaN`, I just ignored and discarded it altogether.

The output will be an array of all combinations. You can `.join("\n")` it to make a string where each combination is separated by a line-break, or you can use `.forEach` to append each combination to a list, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive function with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=a) to flatten the results:

```js
const variants = [{"variantName":"Size","variantItems":["XL","MD","SM"]},{"variantName":"Color","variantItems":["Red","Blue"]},{"variantName":"Material","variantItems":["Plastic","Wood","Ceramic"]}];

const addVariants = (variants) => {
  // destructure the 1st item array, and the rest of the variants
  const add = ([{ variantName, variantItems }, ...variants], row = []) => 
    // iterate the variants and flatten
    [].concat(...variantItems.map((variantItem) => {
      // create a new array for the current row, and the variant string
      const currRow = [...row, `${variantName}: ${variantItem}`];

      // if there are more variants, invoke add with the remaining variants and the current row, or join the array to a string (the end result)
      return variants.length ? add(variants, currRow) : currRow.join(', '); // instead of currRow.join(', ') replace with [currRow] if you want an array
    }));

  return add(variants);
}

const result = addVariants(variants);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .each loop on variants array. Take another array and add object using size, color and material.  So it will become combined array of your requirement. Then print new array data as per requirement using .each loop .