# Looping javascript multi array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

```
var size = ['s','m'];
var color = ['red','blue','black'];
var material = ['cotton','linen'];
```

i want result like :

```
array("s,red,cotton","s,red,linen","s,blue,cotton","s,blue,linen","s,black,cotton","s,black,linen");
array("m,red,cotton","m,red,linen","m,blue,cotton","m,blue,linen","m,black,cotton","m,black,linen");
```

would you like to help me please use javascript or jquery. Thank you :)

Comment: Requires nothing more than three nested loops.

Comment: Related: [Array cross-over loop in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46783496/4642212).

Comment: Have you tried anything to get the expected output? If so please include it otherwise myself and many others will think you have posted this with the expectations of having others do all the work for you which stackoverflow isn't here for that. I am always happy to help -*Those who have tried something of their own and wish to learn from a mistake and solution*

Comment: thank you this is more than enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three loops for each array. Just loop through every array, and append to new array.

```js
var size = ['s','m'];
var color = ['red','blue','black'];
var material = ['cotton','linen'];

var arrayMaterials = []

for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < color.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < material.length; k++) {
      arrayMaterials.push(size[i] + "," + color[j] + "," + material[k]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(arrayMaterials);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in Comment you need 3 loops

```
var size = ['s','m'];
var color = ['red','blue','black'];
var material = ['cotton','linen'];

for (var a = 0; a < size.length; a++) {
  for (var b = 0; b < color.length; b++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < material.length; c++) {
      console.log(size[a] + " , " + color[b] + " , " + material[c]);
    }
  }
}
```